# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.inject.Provider - Quarkus

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, quarkus-panache

This is my Publisher object:

```
import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntity;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import java.time.Instant;

@Entity
public class Publisher extends PanacheEntity {

    // ======================================
    // =             Attributes             =
    // ======================================

    public String name;

    public Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

    // ======================================
    // =           Constructors             =
    // ======================================

    public Publisher(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Publisher() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Publisher{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", createdDate=" + createdDate +
                ", id=" + id +
                '}';
    }
}
```

This is my test:

```
import io.quarkus.test.TestTransaction;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import org.agoncal.quarkus.panache.model.Publisher;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

@QuarkusTest
public class PublisherRepositoryTest {
    @Test
    @TestTransaction
    public void shouldCreateAndFindPublisher() {
        Publisher publisher = new Publisher("name");

        publisher.persist(publisher);
        assertNotNull(publisher.id);

        publisher = publisher.findById(publisher.id);
        assertEquals("name", publisher.name);

    }

}
```

This is the error when doing a `mvn clean install`:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: org.agoncal.quarkus.panache.repository.PublisherRepositoryTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.755 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.agoncal.quarkus.panache.repository.PublisherRepositoryTest
org.agoncal.quarkus.panache.repository.PublisherRepositoryTest.shouldCreateAndFindPublisher  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Provider
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Provider
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.inject.Provider
```

I think the error is quite weird, because I do not use javax in my code...

Comment: vintage-store is still using quarkus 2.x branch as opposite as other projects using Quarkus 3. Mistery solved.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci why not add that as an answer? That way future readers can know immediately what the fix is instead of reading through comments.

Comment: @geoand you're right, done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @geoand pointed out of me I'm moving my comment as answer for future readers.

`vintage-store` is still using Quarkus 2.x branch as opposite as other projects are using Quarkus 3.